# Reaction of sodium with terminal alkyne

Tags: acid-base

Can sodium (just sodium, not with liquid ammonia) react with terminal alkynes in a simple acid-base reaction to form sodium alkynide and dihydrogen (just as it reacts with $\ce{H2O}$ to form sodium hydroxide and $\ce{H2}$)?

Comment: "University Chemistry, Volume 2" by C. Parameshwara Murthy, p 164 says it can. No conditions are listed, though.

Comment: @DGS- but that is in the presence of liq NH3 ,which would react with sodium to form NaNH2. The terminal alkyne then reacts with NaNH2 to liberate H2. I want to know if sodium can directly react with the alkyne

Comment: I guess you may find your proof sooner or later, but you should understand that as sodium is solid and ethyn gaseous, there's not much point in reacting them like this.

Comment: Take a liquid alkyne. Also since they are mildly acidic, the metal must get solvated

Comment: The one I saw didn't mention ammonia, which is kind of crucial to that reaction if that is the mechanism. I'm assuming it wasn't there.

Comment: Sry, you were right @DGS. There isn't ammonia. I saw another reaction on page 161 and thought you had meant that. Thanks, my question is answered